# How to get folder path instead of file path in extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs

How to access path of a folder instead of a file using Ext.form.field in extjs. Is it possible at all in extjs.

I can use the component above but its giving me only the file name without the path to the file.

Or should I use third party tools like jquery or maybe dynamic html/ plain js?

Comment: IIRC getting local file paths via JavaScript is restricted because it is a security issue.

Comment: Aha so maybe with php somehow to get path to folder/file?

Comment: Answer the first comment please - server path or client machine path? If the latter then you can't - PHP makes no difference as its a browser security restriction (for good reason otherwise our machines would be even easier to hack by malicious websites).

Comment: Well actualy i will need to access remote/local hard disk or even maybe cd/dvd. Actually I cannot differentiate if it is server or client machine. Client I guess

Comment: Please explain your case, what do you want to do precisely ?

Comment: Well the thing is, i need a folder path not a file path, and also this extjs component called filefield gives only file name but not the whole path to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get any information on the client's filesystem using a website, for security reasons. Nor Javascript, nor PHP...

Thus, you can't get the path of a client's file.

However, you can do it with a non-website application, installed on his computer.

Comment: To the OP: You can ask the user to provide a file - its called a file upload.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a java, flash, or activex control to do that.

You could also host extjs inside Sencha Desktop Packaging, ie in an installed executable with an embedded browser.

You might be able to get folder access with HTML5, but that would only be a folder local to your domain and heavily restricted.

Otherwise, browser file/folder security restrictions exist for good reason and you should consider files off limits other than upload/download.

Comment: Good advice for the first one and the second :) thnx